# trigger to subtract a column from another in the same table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

Hello i have the table below  :

```
 id | breakname | start | finish | duration 
----+-----------+-------+--------+----------
```

What i need is a trigger to calculate the differance of start and finish in the duration column, when data has been inputted in the other columns.

I have created the following code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION break_duration_insert_update() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    if NEW.duration is null then
        NEW.duration := SET duration = break(finish) - break(start);
    end if;
RETURN NEW;
end
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER break_duration
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON break FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.duration IS NULL)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE break_duration_insert_update()
```

But i am getting the following error when the data is inputted :

```
ERROR:  column "finish" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT finish - start
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT finish - start
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function break_duration_insert_update() line 4 at assignment
```

I have tried inputting the data in without the trigger installed and that worked so i think i have missed something in the trigger coding.

Many Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET duration =` as part of an assignment `:=` is completely wrong.

To access columns of the current rows, you need to prefix every column reference with `new`. So you need

```
NEW.duration := new.finish - new.start;
```

Also you can't assign new values in an `AFTER` trigger, so your trigger needs to be defined as a **BEFORE** trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER break_duration
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON break FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.duration IS NULL)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE break_duration_insert_update()
```

---

Unrelated, but: the language name is an identifier, do not put it in single quotes:

```
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: i have added the changes but have now got this error :ERROR:  function break(time without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT break(new.finish) - break(new.start)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT break(new.finish) - break(new.start)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function break_duration_insert_update() line 4 at assignment

Comment: Apparently you don't need that `break()` thing as far as I understand your question.